# PyGame not responding, any tips?

Tags: python, pygame

When I run this code it doesn't respond. Any tips?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
pygame.font.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500,500])

white = (255,255,255)

font = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 30)
text = font.render(input('Choose a charecter:'),False,(0,0,0))


warrior = pygame.image.load("Warrior.png")
goblin = pygame.image.load("Goblin.png")
kk = pygame.image.load("Karate Kid.png")

#main loop
running = True
while running:
    screen.fill(white)

    screen.blit(text,(255,10))

    screen.blit(warrior, (200,100))
    screen.blit(goblin, (300,100))
    screen.blit(kk, (400,100))

    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT: pygame.quit()
```

I have added the code:

"for event in pygame.event.get():
if event.type == pygame.QUIT: pygame.quit()"

but it still is not working.

Comment: Please post your code here in the question as formatted text, not an external image.

Comment: how?? do i just copy and paste from IDLE

Comment: Yes, the same as you did for all the other text. Just indent the code by 4 spaces.

Comment: You need to handle [events](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get). `for event in pygame.event.get(): if event.type == pygame.QUIT: pygame.quit()`

Answer (score 0):

The `input` command blocks the program execution, so it crashes the window since events cant be processed. Easy fix is to simply to create the window after getting the input. You also need to update the window using `pygame.display.update()`.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
pygame.font.init()

white = (255,255,255)

font = pygame.font.SysFont('Comic Sans MS', 30)
text = font.render(input('Choose a charecter:'),False,(0,0,0))

warrior = pygame.image.load("Warrior.png")
goblin = pygame.image.load("Goblin.png")
kk = pygame.image.load("Karate Kid.png")

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500,500])

#main loop
running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    
    screen.fill(white)

    screen.blit(text,(255,10))


    screen.blit(warrior, (200,100))
    screen.blit(goblin, (300,100))
    screen.blit(kk, (400,100))

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thank you, it kind of works but does not open up a pygame window (only the shell), do you know why?? Also, if it helps, the game is a story game and choosing  a character determines the different missions. I want the characters to know what characters there are and what the characters look like before choosing

Comment: It works for me. You have to enter name in the shell first though obviously because you ask for input in line `text = font.render(input('Choose a charecter:'),False,(0,0,0))` which stops window from appearing because window creating happens after getting the input. Window definitely appears after inputting something. Atleast it does for me.